# session will not save any Variables

Tags: php, session

If i use `session_start();` at the beginning of the file everything works fine, I can save Global Session variables and use them on another page.

If I use the implementation of the recomended site:

```
require('session.class.php');
$session = new session();
// Set to true if using https
$session->start_session('_s', false);
```

instead of

```
session_start();
```

To keep my sessions safe i used this site

https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Management-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL

and followed the instructions. The database is working and sessions work, but only on one page.

I can assign values to `$_SESSION['userName']` but if I do a `var_dump($SESSION)`
on another Page it tells me: `array(0){}`

If I want to know the `session_save_path()` it tells me:

unix:///data/sockets/databases/redis/redis.sock?persistent=1&weight=1&database=0&prefix=PHPREDIS_SESSION-e71589-

If I want to know if the path is writable, it returns false.

I dont know what to do anymore.

My session.php looks like this:

```
<?php

class session {

    function __construct() {
        // set our custom session functions.
        session_set_save_handler(array($this, 'open'), array($this, 'close'), array($this, 'read'), array($this, 'write'), array($this, 'destroy'), array($this, 'gc'));

        // This line prevents unexpected effects when using objects as save handlers.
        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    }

    function start_session($session_name, $secure) {
        // Make sure the session cookie is not accessible via javascript.
        $httponly = true;

        // Hash algorithm to use for the session. (use hash_algos() to get a list of available hashes.)
        $session_hash = 'sha512';

        // Check if hash is available
        if (in_array($session_hash, hash_algos())) {
            // Set the has function.
            ini_set('session.hash_function', $session_hash);
        }
        // How many bits per character of the hash.
        // The possible values are '4' (0-9, a-f), '5' (0-9, a-v), and '6' (0-9, a-z, A-Z, "-", ",").
        ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);

        // Force the session to only use cookies, not URL variables.
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

        // Get session cookie parameters 
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        // Set the parameters
        //$cookieParams["path"]= '/session';

        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
        // Change the session name 
        session_name($session_name);
        // Now we cat start the session
        session_start();
        // This line regenerates the session and delete the old one. 
        // It also generates a new encryption key in the database. 
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }

    function open() {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'zzzz';
        $pass = 'zzzz';
        $name = 'zzzz';
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
        $this->db = $mysqli;
        return true;
    }

    function close() {
        $this->db->close();
        return true;
    }

    function read($id) {
        if (!isset($this->read_stmt)) {
            $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
        }
        $this->read_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->read_stmt->execute();
        $this->read_stmt->store_result();
        $this->read_stmt->bind_result($data);
        $this->read_stmt->fetch();
        $key = $this->getkey($id);
        $data = $this->decrypt($data, $key);
        return $data;
    }

    function write($id, $data) {
        // Get unique key
        $key = $this->getkey($id);
        // Encrypt the data
        $data = $this->encrypt($data, $key);

        $time = time();
        if (!isset($this->w_stmt)) {
            $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        }

        $this->w_stmt->bind_param('siss', $id, $time, $data, $key);
        $this->w_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }

    function destroy($id) {
        if (!isset($this->delete_stmt)) {
            $this->delete_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = ?");
        }
        $this->delete_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->delete_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }

    function gc($max) {
        if (!isset($this->gc_stmt)) {
            $this->gc_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE set_time < ?");
        }
        $old = time() - $max;
        $this->gc_stmt->bind_param('s', $old);
        $this->gc_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }

    private function getkey($id) {
        if (!isset($this->key_stmt)) {
            $this->key_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT session_key FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
        }
        $this->key_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->key_stmt->execute();
        $this->key_stmt->store_result();
        if ($this->key_stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            $this->key_stmt->bind_result($key);
            $this->key_stmt->fetch();
            return $key;
        } else {
            $random_key = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
            return $random_key;
        }
    }

    private function encrypt($data, $key) {

    }

    private function decrypt($data, $key) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Silly question: You do that `require` and `new session()` lines on the top of every page php, right? Not just the one that is working? Also, its including 'session.class.php' or 'session.php'? I would assume you have the right name, because it would fatal error otherwise (your question says one name, then another name).

Comment: Yes I do it on every page. It is including session.php.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the session class code

```
// This line regenerates the session and delete the old one. 
// It also generates a new encryption key in the database. 
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

You're deleting the session data every time you run that line of code.

Comment: I took it out, but nothing changed.